# Is Manu Smriti mentioned in the Ramayana and the Mahabharata?

Tags: mahabharata, ramayana, manu-smriti, smriti, parashara-smriti

It is popular traditional belief that Manu Smriti was there before Ramayana and Mahabharata.

So does Manu Smriti find any mention in the Ramayana and the Mahabharata?

Are any passages quoted in the Ramayana and the Mahabharata?

Any other Smritis like the Parashara, Yajnavalkya, Vishnu, Narada etc mentioned and quoted in the Epics?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, in both the epics, Manusmṛti is referenced.

### 1. Valmiki Ramayan

God Rama invokes it after fatally hurting Vali.

> #### [Chapter 18](https://valmikiramayan.pcriot.com/utf8/kish/sarga18/kishkindha_18_frame.htm), Book IV : Kishkindha Kanda
>
> Valmiki Ramayan
>
> शक्यम् त्वया अपि तत् कार्यम् धर्मम् एव अनुवर्तता ।  **श्रूयते मनुना गीतौ**
> श्लोकौ चारित्र वत्सलौ  ॥ गृहीतौ धर्म कुशलैः तथा तत् चरितम् मयाअ ॥
> ४-१८-३० ॥
>
> > 30. "Had you pursued rightness you too would have done the same deed in imposing such a punishment, and we hear two verses that are given
> >     to the advocacy of good conventions, which the experts of rightness
> >     have also accepted, and **which are said to be coined by Manu**, and I too
> >     conducted myself only as detailed in those verses of law. [4-18-30]

### 2. Mahabharata

References to Manu abounds in the Mahabharata, a few examples of which being.

> #### [Section XLI](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc3905.html), Astika Parva, Adi Parva,
>
> Mahabharata
>
> > Sauti said -
> >
> > The gods cause rain, and rain produces grains and herbs, which are
> > always useful to man. **Manu says, a ruler of the destinies of men is
> > equal (in dignity) to ten Veda-studying priests.**

and

> #### [Section XLIV](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc826369.html), Anusasanika Parva, Anushasana Parva
>
> > Bhishma said -
> >
> > If, instead of selecting a husband for herself, she acts otherwise,
> > she incurs the reproach of Prajapati herself. One should wed that girl
> > who is not a Sapinda of one’s mother or of the same Gotra with one’s
> > father. Even this is the usage (consistent with the sacred law)
> > **which Manu has declared.'**

Comment: Are there mentions about otuer Smritis?

Comment: Umm.. I don't think so. To my limited knowledge, Other smritis not mentioned in the epics,  :) @Optimus

Comment: @Vivikta what about Dharmasutras?